# Is it possible to use UpdateOrInsert where date column is not older than certain date?

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder, laravel-10

Is it possible to use `UpdateOrInsert` (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#update-or-insert), but also where a date column is not older than current time minus defined number of minutes?

For example, the following table:

| id | user_id | comment_type | comment | last_update |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 4 | "Hello" | 2023-06-18 15:55:10 |
| 2 | 11 | 4 | "World" | 2023-06-18 16:05:44 |

I want to update the `last_update` value to the current value (where the user is `user_id` and the comment type is some `comment_type`), only if the `last_update` was made no longer than 5 minutes ago. If not, create a new row.

```
DB::table('some_table')
    ->updateOrInsert(
        ['user_id' => 11, 'comment_type' => 4], // but also where `last_update` is not older than 5 minutes
        ['last_update' => Carbon::now()] // then update `last_update` to current time
    );
```

Comment: You can give this a try: `['user_id' => 11, 'comment_type' => 4, ['last_update', '>', now()->subMinutes(5)->toDateTimeString()]]`

Comment: thank you, it only works when it finds a match, i.e. when it finds a record that was created 5 minutes earlier. After that, when it needs to insert a new record it throws an error: `[SQL Server]Invalid column name '0'. SQL: insert into [some_table] ([user_id], [comment_type], [0], [last_update]) values (111, 4, Array, 2023-06-20 08:15:42.664)).` So the condition turns into an array where it tries to insert `[0]` to it. I instead moved the condition to outside the `updateOrInsert`: `DB::table('some_table')->whereDate(...)`

Comment: Oh! I wasn't aware about that condition.

Comment: No problem :D, and also I had a mistake. I am using Query Builder syntax so I changed `whereDate` to `where` instead

Comment: May be simpler and more obvious to simply do a query first and then update if required.